# SSAS : are dimensions with only Id and Name attributes useless?

Tags: query, ssas, olap, cube

I wonder if it is worth creating a dimension with only one column (e.g. Name) in addition to its Id Column. This dimension would be referenced by a fact containing a reference to the Id attribute of the above dimension.

Wouldn't be better to include directly the Name in the fact (the dimension is referenced only one time by the fact)?

And my second question is am I expected to create an MDX query manually in the case of the name directly included in the fact ? Won(t be the queries more difficult to write?

thank you.